# Best proactive when implementing adView

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am making a game and I would like the ad to be visible during the menu but not when the game is actually being played.

If I simple set the adView Visibility to INVISIBLE when I don't want it shown then the ad will not refresh and thus i don't think will register with admob.

Is there an accepted way of implementing ads like this?

edit* Code in main activity to add the adView

```
private void initialiseAd()
{   
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
adView.setLayoutParams(lp);
//load ads
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
//add the adView to the window
mainLayout.addView(adView);
}
```

Comment: the code to add my advert is in my main activity. it is added to a relative layout after my SurfaceView for my game so it is positioned on top.

Comment: I mean that you have to include the relevant code in your question, without it noone will be able to help you.

Comment: ah, sorry, i've edited the question with the code

Comment: If you don't want the Ad to appear then don't put it in the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're facing it is correct, you can easily hide the `AdView` simply wrapping it within a `FrameLayout` (which you already seem to be doing) and calling the `setVisibility()` method over it.

If you're using `Activity`, this would be the way:

```
FrameLayout containingFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_containing_framelayout_id);
containingFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If you're using `Fragment`:

```
FrameLayout containingFrame = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ad_containing_framelayout_id);
containingFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: thats done the trick. thanks the ad is now showing as reloading each time it appears